# Shift key released when pressing numpad

Tags: javascript, keyboard-events

Add keyboard listeners:

```
document.addEventListener("keydown", e=>console.log('keydown', e.code), true);
document.addEventListener("keyup", e=>console.log('keyup', e.code), true);
```

Press Shift+Num1:

```
keydown ShiftLeft
keyup ShiftLeft
keydown Numpad1
keyup Numpad1
keydown ShiftLeft
keyup ShiftLeft
```

Why is it unpressing Shift before sending numpad key? Is it a Chrome bug?

```js
document.addEventListener("keydown", e => console.log('keydown', e.code, e.shiftKey), true);
document.addEventListener("keyup", e => console.log('keyup', e.code, e.shiftKey), true);
```

Comment: You need to check `e.shiftKey` to catch the combination.  I don't know why it does a keyup first.

Comment: It's `false`. By the way, `key` is set to `End`, so it does some weird translation for me. I just want to handle shift+num1...

Comment: `e.shiftKey` is true for me when I press shift+num1.  I tested it just now.

Comment: I can't seem to replicate this behavior and I'm also using Chrome, could it be something with your keyboard instead? (Chrome version 73.0.3683.86)

Comment: Have you tried with numlock on?

Comment: Yes, I have tried it with numlock both on and off.  It works in each case.  I see "keyup End true" and "keydown End true" in my console log.

Comment: Apparently it's not possible to use shift+numpad for hotkeys in Windows. Do you happen to be using a different OS? https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20040906-00/?p=37953

Comment: I am using Windows 10.

Comment: It might be different for Win10, but I see the "effect" on Win7, in multiple browsers. Also, having NumLock enabled, pressing Num1 or Num7 emits a 1 or a 7, pressing Shift+Num1 or Shift+Num7 back and forth between the end and the beginning (either the page or right now in the comment box line), **and** pressing Shift+Shift+Num1 or Shift+Shift+Num7 jumps to the end/start of the comment line, also selecting it (!)

Comment: Btw the double-Shift thing works with the JS code too, only ShiftRight is getting released, and shiftKey remains true.

Answer (score 3):

It seems that Shift overrides numlock in Windows and results in this behavior. Chrome has nothing to do with it.

https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20040906-00/?p=37953

Answer (score 1):

This behavior is a windows feature/quirk.

Here is what you can do if you want to capture shift-numpad events:

1. Save the timestamp when the shift key is released
2. In you keydown event check how long ago that was. If less than 50ms or so, it is *very* likely that the user pressed shift + a numpad key (and not the arrow keys).

   ```
   let iShiftReleaseTime;

   window.addEventListener('keyup', function (e) {
       if(e.keyCode == 16) //shift key
           iShiftReleaseTime = Date.now();
   });

   window.addEventListener('keydown', function (e) {
       if ((Date.now() - iShiftReleaseTime) < 50) {
           if (e.keyCode == 45) console.log("Shift + Numpad 0 was pressed");
           if (e.keyCode == 35) console.log("Shift + Numpad 1 was pressed");
           if (e.keyCode == 40) console.log("Shift + Numpad 2 was pressed");
           if (e.keyCode == 34) console.log("Shift + Numpad 3 was pressed");
           if (e.keyCode == 37) console.log("Shift + Numpad 4 was pressed");
           if (e.keyCode == 12) console.log("Shift + Numpad 5 was pressed");
           if (e.keyCode == 39) console.log("Shift + Numpad 6 was pressed");
           if (e.keyCode == 36) console.log("Shift + Numpad 7 was pressed");
           if (e.keyCode == 38) console.log("Shift + Numpad 8 was pressed");
           if (e.keyCode == 33) console.log("Shift + Numpad 9 was pressed");
       }
       else {
           if (e.keyCode == 37) console.log("left arrow key was pressed");
           if (e.keyCode == 38) console.log("up arrow key was pressed");
           if (e.keyCode == 39) console.log("right arrow key was pressed");
           if (e.keyCode == 40) console.log("down arrow key was pressed");
           //etc...
       }
   });
   ```

Comment: This solution — if it works — should be very flaky.  I think [`Martin Hennings`’ solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24822505/how-to-tell-if-shift-is-pressed-on-numpad-input-with-numlock-on-or-at-least-get/25034940#25034940) has a much better chance to be robust.

Comment: And: the “faked” key events are generated with **exactly** the same timestamp as “the causing it” key.  (Still, one cannot rely on such timestamps: on a busy system, when the system may be able to react on a key, a second keys may have already arrived.  So the timestamps would be the same…)

Comment: @IlyaZakharevich If you think the solution you linked works better, please post it as an actual answer to this question in **Javascript**. My solution (while not appropriate for rocket control) works well enough for most use cases.

Comment: In my experience: in the long term, “works well enough for most use cases” ⇔ “does not work” (read: causes more problems than it solves¹⁾).  But as to helping you to convert existing code to JS: sorry! I try to avoid JS whenever possible.

Comment: ¹⁾ … unless you have some tools to decrease users’ expectations.  (For example, the only user is yourself. ¼)

Comment: @IlyaZakharevich Lots of assumptions on your side: "if it works", "should be", "the only user is yourself". I didn't want you to write an answer so it could help me, but to actually provide something constructive to this webpage. So far, your comments have only been presumptuous and destructive while you haven't provided a better answer yourself. Please be more constructive and less condescending!

Comment: I have no clue why you think that `Martin Hennings`’ solution is “not constructive”.  Please explain!  (And, BTW, people who are not afraid to follow links may want to inspect how Emacs does it.  In `w32fnc.c`, IIRC.  But this is more or less what Martin suggests.)